# Hostgator changes cronjob by itself

Tags: laravel, cron, centos

I have installed laravel 5.4 on my server, and configured cronjob as it is stated in the documentation * * * * * 
It works fine on my private server (ubuntu), but one of projects is on the client's server on hostgator (Linux CentOS)
Anytime I set cronjob on  * * * * * , after some time it changes it to  */18 or */17
I have no idea why it happens and what should i do to fix it. i need cronjob to run everyminute

Comment: That's because you can't run crons every minutes on Hostgator, it has to be once an hour... OVH has the same kind of behaviour :/ I've found a workaround here http://www.weblogin.fr/blog/mutualise-ovh-et-laravel-scheduler (in french) look ta the method called `scheduleRunsHourly`. Basically it sets the minutes to `*` so your schedules run hourly so take that to account!